# Scheduler with blocking=False

Tags: python, scheduler, python-multithreading, python-sched

The Python scheduler works well with default value `blocking=True`:

```
import sched, time
def print_time(a):
    print("From print_time", time.time(), a)
s = sched.scheduler()
s.enter(2, priority=1, action=print_time, argument=(1,))
s.enter(2, priority=2, action=print_time, argument=(2,))
print(time.time())
s.run()  # blocks until the last scheduled task is finished
print('finished')
```

but I can't make it work with `blocking=False`.

Indeed with:

```
s.run(block=False)  
print('finished')
```

the script stops immediately so obviously it does not work (this is normal behaviour). But with:

```
s.run(block=False)  
time.sleep(10)     # sleeping to make sure the script does not terminate immediately,
print('finished')  # but in real situation, there would be other tasks here
```

it does not work either: the tasks are strangely not executed.

I don't really understand the documentation:

> If blocking is false executes the scheduled events due to expire soonest (if any) and then return the deadline of the next scheduled call in the scheduler (if any).

**How to use scheduler in `blocking=False` mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: the `blocking=False` mode allows to do other things in the meantime and poll the new events every now and then. This works:

```
import sched, time

def print_time(a):
    print("From print_time", time.time(), a)

s = sched.scheduler()
s.enter(2, priority=1, action=print_time, argument=(1,))
s.enter(2, priority=2, action=print_time, argument=(2,))

for _ in range(50):
   s.run(blocking=False)
   time.sleep(0.1)  # in a real situation, this would be some other tasks

print('finished')
```